# Different Response From cURL and Golang POST - Can't Understand Why

Tags: curl, go

I'm trying to get a response from a server using golang's `http` client.

The request I'm looking to perform via go should be identical to the following `curl` command:

```
curl  --data "fulladdress=22280+S+209th+Way%2C+Queen+Creek%2C+AZ+85142"  'http://www.homefacts.com/hfreport.html'
```

I've coded the equivalent go code, and also tried using a nice service called [curl-to-go](https://mholt.github.io/curl-to-go/), which generates the following go code for the above `curl` request:

```
 // Generated by curl-to-Go: https://mholt.github.io/curl-to-go

body := strings.NewReader(`fulladdress=22280+S+209th+Way%2C+Queen+Creek%2C+AZ+85142`)
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://www.homefacts.com/hfreport.html", body)
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

The problem is that I keep getting a different response between the `curl` command and the go code. The `curl` command returns this response body:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.homefacts.com/address/Arizona/Maricopa-County/Queen-Creek/85142/22280-S-209th-Way.html"/></head></html>
```

which is the expected result. However the go code returns a lengthly `HTML` which is not the expected result.

I've tried adding `--verbose` to the `curl` command to copy all it's headers, so I added the following headers via my go code:

```
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "curl/7.51.0")
req.Header.Set("Accept", "*/*")
req.Header.Set("Content-Length", "56")
```

But still no joy, the output from the go code remains different than the `curl` one.

Any ideas on how to get the same `curl` response from go?

Comment: Because `go` follows redirection and `curl` don't?

Comment: @u_mulder you are right! changing the client to not use re-direct solve this. If you want to submit this as an answer feel free and I'll accept it (used code from here: stackoverflow.com/questions/23297520/how-can-i-make-the-go-http-client-not-follow-redirects-automatically)

Comment: I think you can answer you question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @u_mulder for pointing me out in the right direction. It seems that the default go `http` client follows the redirect header by default, while `curl` does not.

Here is the updated code that generates the same results between go and `curl`:

```
body := strings.NewReader(`fulladdress=22280+S+209th+Way%2C+Queen+Creek%2C+AZ+85142`)
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://www.homefacts.com/hfreport.html", body)
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

client := &http.Client{
    CheckRedirect: func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
        return http.ErrUseLastResponse
    },
}

resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
```