# Go does not send HTTP request, but curl does

Tags: go, curl, request, centos7

I have a problem sending request to specific URL (it's a mail server exchange) in the production environment.

```
tr := &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    },
}
client := http.Client{
    Transport: tr,
}
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://mail.example.com", nil)
req.Header.Set("Host", "mail.example.com")
req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "curl/7.29.0")
req.Header.Set("Accept", "*/*")
_, err := client.Do(req)
```

But this code returns error:

```
Get "https://mail.example.com": read tcp [server_ip]:53006->[destination_server_ip]:443: read: connection timed out
```

after prevent redirect:

```
    client := http.Client{
        Transport: tr,
        CheckRedirect: func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
            return http.ErrUseLastResponse
        },
    }
```

error changed to:

```
Get "https://mail.example.com": read tcp [server_ip]:53120->[destination_server_ip]:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

**the above code also works well in the local environment.**

But Linux curl in server (the production server that Go code does not work well) works well:

```
curl -I https://mail.example.com 

 HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
 Cache-Control: no-cache
 Pragma: no-cache
 Content-Length: 0
 Location: https://mail.example.com/owa/
 Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
 Date: Thu, 15 Apr 2021 10:00:46 GMT
 Connection: close
```

I thought the problem was with the firewall (CentOS firewalld) and I stopped it, but I still have the problem.

Comment: you can use wireshark(tshark) to check differences between these two requests

Comment: The Go program follows the redirect. The `curl` command does not.  See [Different Response From cURL and Golang POST](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42185635/5728991), [How Can I Make the Go HTTP Client NOT Follow Redirects Automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23297520/5728991)

Comment: @CeriseLimón Incidentally, for testing, I added this code for prevent redirection, and my error changed to this. `Get "https://mail.example.com": read tcp [server_ip]:53120->[destination_server_ip]:443: read: connection reset by peer`